# Android OpenGLES unexpected end of source compile failed

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

i tired every chunk to correct flaws, but can't get it working!
Below is my Activity code!!

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ActivityManager actMan = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    ConfigurationInfo mConfigInfo = actMan.getDeviceConfigurationInfo();
    boolean isES2Compat = (mConfigInfo.reqGlEsVersion >= 0x20000);
    Log.e("oGl-es v",mConfigInfo.getGlEsVersion()+":"+ mConfigInfo.reqGlEsVersion);
    if(isES2Compat){

        mGLSurfaceView = new MySurface(getApplication());//(this); 
        renderSet = true;
        Log.e("render","set");
    }
    this.setContentView(mGLSurfaceView);
}
```

Below is MySurface class

```
public class MySurface extends GLSurfaceView {

    public MySurface(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
        setRenderer(new MyTestRenderer(context));
    }
}
```

Below is renderer class.

public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {

```
    GLES20.glClearColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.01f, 0.8f);

    float[] triangleVertices = { 
            0f,0f, 0.0f,
            15f,0f,0.0f,
            15f,15f,0.0f,
            15f,15f,0.0f,//Triangle2
            0f,15f,0.0f,
            0f,0f,0.0f
    };

    myTriangleVertices = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(triangleVertices.length * bytesPerFloat).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
    //copy data from Dalvik’s memory to native memory
    myTriangleVertices.put(triangleVertices);
    myTriangleVertices.position(0);

//  String vertexShader = ShadersUtils.readShadersToString(context,R.raw.v_shader);
//  String fragmentShader = ShadersUtils.readShadersToString(context,R.raw.f_shader);
    final String vertexShader = 
            "attribute vec4 aPosition;\n" +
            "void main(){\n" +              
            "gl_Position = aPosition;\n" +              
            "}\n"        ;
    final String fragmentShader = 
            "uniform vec4 uColor;\n" +              
            "void main(){\n" +              
            "gl_FragColor = uColor;\n" +                
            "}\n" 
             ;


    vertexShaderHandle = compileVertexShader(vertexShader);
    fragmentShaderHandle = compileFragmentShader(fragmentShader);

    linkProgramHandle = ShadersUtils.linkShadersVF(vertexShaderHandle, fragmentShaderHandle);


    GLES20.glUseProgram(linkProgramHandle);
    uColorLocation = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(linkProgramHandle,"u_Color");
    aPositionLOcation = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(linkProgramHandle,"a_Position");


    myTriangleVertices.position(0);//setting to start position

    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(aPositionLOcation,3,GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 3*4, myTriangleVertices); //refer for meaning of arguments
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(aPositionLOcation);



}
```

LogCat output is

```
12-19 10:35:12.785: E/compilei(620): source
12-19 10:35:12.785: E/ss(620): attribute vec4 aPosition;
12-19 10:35:12.785: E/ss(620): void main()
12-19 10:35:12.785: E/ss(620): {
12-19 10:35:12.785: E/ss(620): gl_Position = aPosition;
12-19 10:35:12.785: E/ss(620): }
12-19 10:35:12.785: E/Results of compile(620): Compile failed.
12-19 10:35:12.785: E/Results of compile(620): ERROR: Unexpected end of source found
12-19 10:35:12.785: E/Results of compile(620): ERROR: 1 compilation errors. No code generated.
12-19 10:35:12.785: E/compilei(620): source
12-19 10:35:12.785: E/ss(620): uniform vec4 uColor;
12-19 10:35:12.785: E/ss(620): void main()
12-19 10:35:12.785: E/ss(620): {
12-19 10:35:12.785: E/ss(620): gl_FragColor = uColor;
12-19 10:35:12.785: E/ss(620): }
12-19 10:35:12.785: E/Results of compile(620): Compile failed.
12-19 10:35:12.785: E/Results of compile(620): ERROR: Unexpected end of source found
12-19 10:35:12.785: E/Results of compile(620): ERROR: 1 compilation errors. No code generated.
```

The code for functions used!

```
public static int compileVertexShader(String shaderString){
    return CompileShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER,shaderString);

}

public static int compileFragmentShader(String shaderString){
    return CompileShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER,shaderString);

}

static  int CompileShader(int type, String shaderString) {
final int shaderID = GLES20.glCreateShader(type); //create shader object of type
    if(shaderID == 0)
        Log.e("unable to","createShader");

    else{
        //Toast.makeText(, shaderString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        Log.e("compilei","source");
        GLES20.glShaderSource(type, shaderString); 
        GLES20.glCompileShader(shaderID); 
        Log.e("ss",shaderString);
        final int[] compileStatus = new int[1];

        GLES20.glGetShaderiv(shaderID, GLES20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS, compileStatus, 0);

        Log.e("Results of compile" , GLES20.glGetShaderInfoLog(shaderID));

        if (compileStatus[0] == 0) {
            // If it failed, delete the shader object.
            GLES20.glDeleteShader(shaderID);
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return shaderID;
}
```

Comment: `String vertexShader = ShadersUtils.readShadersToString(context,R.raw.v_shader);`
 This reads from the file v_shader.glsl which contains `attribute vec4 a_Position;
void main()
{
gl_Position = a_Position;
}
` also not working!Please some one help, this wasted more than 5days for me, i have seen many examples from github,google code, all using similar formatting of shader code ,they all works,except this code.

Comment: What hardware do you use? YMMV depending on GPU and Android version (namely, OpenGL ES drivers). Also, while error message doesn't seem to be directly related to this but according to specs you must explicitly specify float precision in fragment shader (simply add `precision mediump float;` at the very beginning of fragment shader).

Comment: Please provide code of `compileVertexShader()` and `compileFragmentShader()` too

Comment: @keaukraine i tested the same in Samsung s3, Odroid E & A. Regarding precision, i can't get you, could you please somwhat elaborate?

Comment: @keaukraine. from `/system/vendor/lib/egl/` i see `libGLESv2_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so`, so my GPU should be Adrena POWERVR-SGX540-120

Comment: Regarding precision: just add precision qualifier `precision mediump float;` at the very beginning of your shader.
You can read more in specs http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/2.0/GLSL_ES_Specification_1.0.17.pdf , page 36

Comment: I also use a POWERVR GPU on my archos tablet. @keaukraine is right. I have to add `precision` statement in the shader.

Comment: @FabienR, adding `precision` doesn't solved it!! Still looking for the cause and solution